# How to add column to output data frame from within parallel foreach loop in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

In the code below, I am trying to run the "percentiles_func" function within a foreach loop in R.  The function produces a list of data frames (inside the variable percents), from which I want to copy the output to a very large output data frame (normals_1981_2010).

```
    vars <- c('tmin_F','tavg_F','tmax_F','pp')
    windows <- c(15,15,15,29)
    perc_list <- c('obs','smoothed_obs','windowed_obs','smoothed_windowed_obs')
    percs <- c('00','02','05','10','20','25','30','33','40','50','60','66','70','75','80','90','95','98','100')
    vcols <- seq(1,19,1)

  cl <- makeCluster(6)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  foreach (v=1:4,.packages=c('dplyr','lubridate')) %dopar% {
      percents <- percentiles_func('1981-01-01','2010-12-31',vars[v], windows[v])

 for (pl in 1:4){
   for (p in 1:19){
     normals_1981_2010 <- normals_1981_2010 %>% 
      mutate(!!paste0(vars[v],'_daily',perc_list[pl],'_perc',percs[p]) := percents[[pl]][,vcols[p]])}}}
```

Instead of adding the columns to the large output data frame (which is outside the loop, in the global environment), the output looks like this:

```
 [[1]]
 NULL

 [[2]]
 NULL

 [[3]]
 NULL

 [[4]]
 NULL
```

I've seen the .export argument, but don't understand how to use it.  Is there a way to get the foreach loop to add the columns to the output data frame via the mutate statement?  Is it even possible?

Comment: Could you restructure the foreach block to return all those calculated percents elements (I assume this is what is time consuming), then afterwards inject them into the bigger data frame where they belong?

Comment: That works very well, actually.  Thank you.